# How to check if the date in a cell is an actual date or a string date?

Tags: excel, vba, date, locale

At work we are using Office 365 Excel's file as a booking system. It has multiple tabs for each site where each record has a booking date. There is problem of date formatting - basically the default locale is set to `"mm/dd/yyyy"` however the date is displayed in `"dd/mm/yyyy"`. When people add rows manually (normally booking slots are generated automatically for each day) and just type in date in a wrong format instead of copying date value from the adjacent cell it displays right, but the cell value in the top bar is different, but when opening this file in the `Desktop App` it does not see this as different values at all. Only when applying filter, there are dates, and string date values you can filter by. This causes some of the dates not being picked up by the macros while creating reports, or importing data based on the date.

I've been thinking of writing an utility macro that would sanitize all dates based on the dates up and down to the current date, however I am not sure if this is the best way to go. I don't think I can just change the locale settings for all users as for what I read in docs this will make changes only to the single user settings and I am not really sure how this will affect overall functionality of whole system. Is there any way it can be done rather more easily than parsing this massive file or manually finding this dates?

It is a real pain as this file was designed long time before I came to the team and now I am trying to make this less error prone.

Thanks for any clues in advance!

Comment: For `VBA` there is function `IsDate()` try that.

Comment: @Harun24HR careful `IsDate` just tells you if a string can be read as date. It does **not** tell you if the cell content is a real numeric date! `IsDate` will return `True` even if the cell contains a string that looks like a date.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Oh my bad! I was not aware about this information.

Comment: No worries ;) For your interest: [IsDate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) (see the examples there).

Comment: Another possibility is to have them select the date from a calendar (Date Picker).

Comment: Is this a Microsoft Teams thing?  I've found in the last two companies I've worked for the IT department just left everything as default when it installed - so dates in American format, and times are out by about 8 hours, English words are underlined in red.  Clicking the user profile and changing the settings in Teams generally sorts it out.

Comment: Its not only MS Teams thing as we only have this issue in the shared excel files over the SharePoint. It all comes down to doing a better job in the initial setup - but sometimes for the person not involved that much with the process of using that thing is hard to spot all the edge cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real dates are numeric. So you can check with `IsNumeric`

```
If IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value2) Then
    Debug.Print "date"
Else
    Debug.Print "string"
End If
```

Note that you need to check `.Value2` not `.Value`

Comment: Great, this worked like a charm in the utility macro process! I have posted the code if anyone would be interested in the solution

Answer (score 1):

Peh's answer guided me to the right solution. Here is the whole code if anyone would came across similar problem:

```
Sub SanitizeDates()
    ' ---
    ' Utility macro that goes over all live sheets and checks all rows
    ' for the string dates that have been input manually
    ' and converts it to an actual Date values.
    ' ---

    Debug.Print "--- Log Start"
    
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim Errors As Integer
    Dim TotalErrors As Integer
    TotalErrors = 0
    Errors = 0

    Dim Tracker As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    
    Dim CurrentDateValue As Variant
    Dim NewDate As Date
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim nRow As Long
    
    Set Tracker = ThisWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each WS In Tracker.Worksheets
        If WS.Visible And Not WS.Name = "Matrix" Then ' if worksheet is not visible and not a Matrix
            If InStr(1, WS.Name, "Template", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' if worksheet is not a template
            
                Errors = 0
                
                RowCount = WS.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                
                'loop over all rows in table
                For nRow = 1 To RowCount
                    With WS.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
                    
                        ' check if the cell is a black bar / divider
                        If Not .Cells(nRow, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                            If Not IsNumeric(.Cells(nRow, 3).Value2) Then
                                                                
                                On Error GoTo SkipInvalid
                                NewDate = DateValue(.Cells(nRow, 3).Value2)
                                .Cells(nRow, 3).Value2 = NewDate
                                Errors = Errors + 1
                                
                                'Error logging
                                'Call LogError(.Cells(nRow, 5), .Cells(nRow, 15), "Date Format - dev")
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
SkipInvalid:
                Next nRow
                
                TotalErrors = TotalErrors + Errors
                
                If Errors Then
                    Prompt = Prompt & "Found " & Errors & " errors in " & WS.Name & vbCrLf
                    Debug.Print "Found " & Errors & " errors in " & WS.Name
                End If
                
            End If
        End If
    Next WS
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Debug.Print "--- Log End"
    
    If TotalErrors Then
        MsgBox (Prompt & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Total of " & TotalErrors & " errors found. All data sanitized successfully.")
    Else
        MsgBox ("No errors found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `DateValue` **guesses** the date from a string based on the date format set in the operating system (Windows). If you have a string like `02/03/2021` no computer in the entire world can say if it is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` it is just impossible to say that with only the string itself. Therefore you code might guess right or wrong, in worst case you end up with the wrong date in your data. The only reliable string date is the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format `yyyy-mm-dd` (https://xkcd.com/1179/) as here cannot be any confusion.

Comment: So if you know which date format your strings are it is better not to let Excel guess and split the string and put it together as real date. For example if you know for sure all string dates are `dd/mm/yyyy` then use `Part = Split(YourStringDate, "/")` and make a real date `RealDate = DateSerial(Part(2), Part(1), Part(0))`. This way you tell Excel what to do instead of letting it guess.

Comment: makes sense! I will correct this definitely

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem derives from the fact people are entering invalid dates.
You may try to apply a data validation on the cells to sanitize during data entry.
Data validation allows to set a cell as Date and then you can specify a date range. So only valid dates within that range will be allowed.

[image]

Comment: Data Validation is setup on all the Date Cells, however there are some cases where this does not help, like additional rows have to be added manually or data is copy/paste from an external source like a booking form